# what the difference between call R S3 method and directly call the function from global environment

Tags: r, environment, r-s3

I create a S3 method for printing the object name:

```
printc = function(...) {
  UseMethod("printc")
}

#' @export add_dataset.data.frame

printc.data.frame = function(...){
  
  xs <- rlang::quos(..., .named = TRUE)
  return(rlang::names2(xs))
}
```

and the there are two way to call it:

```
b <- printc(iris)

c <- printc.data.frame(iris)
```

the result b is `<df[,5]>`, istead of c: `iris`, could someone know the reason? how can I make the S3 method generate a result like "iris"?

when I try to figure out how S3 dispatch this method,
`sloop::s3_dispatch(printc(iris))`, it does dispatch to the `printc.data.frame`? I think it may relate to the environment.